# Temporarily save Word document changes

Tags: c#, com, interop, ms-word

I'm using Interop to create a "custom word editor", basically I've incorporated MS Word on my application and I allow users to edit a document and insert custom fields from a predefined list.

I provide a "Preview" option to see how the document will appear when the data is added.

The users can start editing a template on my application, and at any time they can hit preview and the preview should appear with the latest changes.

I want the user to be able to preview the document without saving the changes, the problem is that when I invoke SaveAs() on the document (to create a temp file that I can use as the input for the preview generator), the editor opens the temp document.

Is there a way to save a copy of the document being edited but keep the original (open) document with its changes unsaved?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I know this can be done in pre-2007 Word, as described in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/pranavwagh/archive/2008/04/03/how-to-do-a-save-copy-as-in-word.aspx).

Unfortunately, that solution does not work in Word 2007.

How about using a temp file from the get-go, and only saving to the "true" file when the user indicates that he or she is done?